# Can't read property value of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to make a Shopping Cart using HTML, CSS, Javascript, and JQuery. Whenever you click Add to Cart under the orange it will make almost all of the HTML elements disappear and only display the table Shopping Cart. But when you change the quantity and click Update Cart, I am getting an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null Shopping Cart" in the console. I've looked everywhere to find a solution to this but couldn't find one. I appreciate the help.

https://jsfiddle.net/John_Badew/er9z3kg1/10/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bButton").click(function() {
    $(".sTable").append("<td>Banana</td");
    $(".sTable").append("<td><form><input id = 'bupdateQuantity' type='number' name='quantity' min='1'max='10'></form></td>");
    $(".sTable").append("<td>50 cents</td>");
    $(".sTable").append("<td id = 'bPrice'></td>");

  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#oButton").click(function() {
    $(".sTable").append("<td>Orange</td");
    $(".sTable").append("<td><form><input id = 'oupdateQuantity' type='number' name='ooquantity' min='1'max='10'></form></td>");
    $(".sTable").append("<td>75 cents</td>");
    $(".sTable").append("<td id = 'oPrice'></td>");

  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(".disappear").hide();
  });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").click(bquantity)
  $(".button").click(oquantity)

});


function bquantity() {
  var quantity = document.getElementById('bupdateQuantity').value;
  var price = quantity * .5;
  var bPrice = document.getElementById('bPrice');
  bPrice.innerHTML = "$" + price;
}

function oquantity() {
  var oquantity = document.getElementById('oupdateQuantity').value;
  console.log(oquantity);
  var oprice = oquantity * .75;
  var oPrice = document.getElementById('oPrice');
  oPrice.innerHTML = "$" + oprice;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: aqua;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.button:hover {
  color: #4CAF50;
  background-color: white;
}

.sTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>



  <div id="navigation" class="disappear">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="index.html">
          <h2>Home</h2>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Cart</h2>
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <table cellspacing="50" class="disappear">
    <th>
      <h2>Banana</h2>
    </th>
    <th>
      <h2>Orange</h2>
    </th>
    <th>
      <h2>Apple</h2>
    </th>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="https://img.purch.com/rc/300x200/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5saXZlc2NpZW5jZS5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL2kvMDAwLzA2NS8xNDkvb3JpZ2luYWwvYmFuYW5hcy5qcGc="></td>
      <td><img src="https://www.oasis-botanical.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/orange-web.jpg" alt="Image description" width="215px" />
      </td>
      <td><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/918YNa3bAaL._SL1500_.jpg" width="200px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h3>50 cents per bunch</h3>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h3>75 cents per orange</h3>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h3>60 cents per apple</h3>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button id="bButton">Add To Cart</button></td>
      <td><button id="oButton">Add To Cart</button></td>
      <td><button id="aButton">Add To Cart</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="shoppingTable" class="sTable" style="margin-top:50px;">
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <a href="#" class="button" class="disappear">Update Cart</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".button").click(bquantity)
  $(".button").click(oquantity)
});
```

On "Update" button click event you update both bquantity and oquantity but you don't have both html created. You only have the one related to the button clicked (bButton/oButton). You have to separate these events.

Comment: I’m not sure if I understand. How would I separate these events

Comment: @JohnBadew use two different update buttons and trigger the related event based on the button you clicked